# Can we create views over a raster table in Postgis2.0?

Tags: qgis, raster, postgresql, postgis-2.0

**Is it possible to create PostgreSQL views over a table that contains raster data?**

I have succeeded in creating the view but the entry in `raster_columns` is not correct (all the raster info is missing). Also, I couldn't open the SQL view using QGIS (most probably because of the raster_columns not being correct).

It's the same situation as this question on [gemetry_columns & views](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35427/postgis-2-0-public-geometry-columns-view-does-not-contain-correct-info-for-vie/35471#35471) but for the raster column I couldn't find the correct syntax to force the typemod during creation of the view.

All that I could find is this:

> raster(ARRAY['8BUI','8BUI','8BUI'], 4326,0.5,-0.5, ...);

but what follows after "..." is a mystery.

**Has anybody managed to create a view with correct entries in raster_columns?**

A short example will be highly appreciated.

Comment: RT_Raster_Overview? http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_raster.xml.html#RT_Raster_Overviews

Comment: Raster Overview = a lower resolution caricature of a higher resolution table. I don't need a lower resolution, I need a portion of the big raster at the original quality available as a SQL view.

Answer (score 2):

Did you create your raster table using raster2pgsql, or specify the -C flag (apply raster constraints) during the load operation? If not, you'll need to apply those constraints with [AddRasterConstraints()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/RT_AddRasterConstraints.html) to ensure that the relevant information about your raster data are registered correctly.

Comment: The tables were created with raster2pgsql having the -C attribute set: `raster2pgsql -I -C -e -Y -F -s 4326 -t 10x10 d:\temp\RasterData\US.tif public.us | %POSTGRESQL_FOLDER%\psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d DBTest`